# How i get CoreData Attribute when is not nil

Tags: swift, core-data, attributes, nsdate

I have a Alert with Date Picker and i save the NSDate in CoreData. So when the NSDate is safety then it´s doesn´t show the Alert anymore. So i need a func from CoreData Attribute to request the Attribute is it nil or not nil. Have anything an idea how i can do that ?

Comment: How are you saving this date? Is it a part of an entity?

Comment: Yes is it, the Entity name is "Everyday" and i have 4 Attributes in there "BoCount", "DiCoutn", "BoDate" and "DIDate". The Typs by Coutn is Int and by Date is Date. I need by "BoDate" is it nil or not nil

Comment: Have you an idea what i can do there ? Thanks for your Help.

Answer (score 3):

What you can do is add a predicate to your fetchRequest that checks whether values are nil as so:

```
    let fetchRequest       = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "entNameHere")
    let predicate          = NSPredicate(format: "%K != nil", "attributeNameHere")
    fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
```

executing the request should you get you all entries where the attribute is not nil. Conversely you could use '== nil' to find those that are nil

Answer (score -1):

To check if something is `nil` you can do optional unwrapping. Let's assume you have a property called `boDate` that is an optional and can be `nil`

```
if let boDate = boDate {
    // property is not nil here
} else {
    // property is nil
}
```